# NameError on constructor in ruby

Tags: ruby, constructor, module

I'm trying to set a default value in an instance variable. I'm doing:

```
module MyModule::MyOtherModule
  class MyClass
    attr_accessor :point

    def initialize
      @point = Point.new(0,1)
    end
  end
end

module MyModule
  class Point
    attr_accessor :x, :y

    def initialize(x, y)
      @x = x
      @y = y
    end
  end
end
```

Point is also a class I wrote. The funny thing is that whenever I run this sample, I get:

```
uninitialized constant MyModule::MyOtherModule::MyClass::Point (NameError)
```

But if I move the assignment to another method instead of the constructor - say, foo - the error doesn't happen.  I think this suggests it's not something related to module location. So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module =! module

Class =! class

In this case Module and Class are constants in Ruby so in essence this code is incorrect. Proper module and class constructs are downcased. That's the first.

Second, to answer your question, we would need to look on how actually Point class definitions looks, and how do you instantiate MyClass. In the moment message is clear: `uninitialized constant`, it cannot find Point anywhere in a scope.

EDIT

```
module MyModule
  module MyOtherModule
    class MyClass
      attr_accessor :point

      def initialize
        #as mentioned by nas
        @point = MyModule::Point.new(0,1)
      end
    end
  end
end

module MyModule
  class Point
    attr_accessor :x, :y

    def initialize(x, y)
      @x = x
      @y = y
    end
  end
end

obj = MyModule::MyOtherModule::MyClass.new()
puts obj.point.x #=> 0
puts obj.point.y #=> 1
```

Comment: thanks for the comments, I added the actual code with some names changed

Comment: @Thiago: I updated post with corrected code. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Since your Point class is in scope of MyModule so best practice would be to access it like so `MyModule::Point`. A slight change in your MyClass constructor would be:

```
def initialize
  @point = MyModule::Point.new(0,1)
end
```